# Como colocar interrogação numa url amigável do htaccess no lugar que eu desejar?

Tags: htaccess, url

Estou usando esse código:

```
RewriteRule ^editar/candidato=([0-9]+)&admin=([0-9]+)/?$ http://localhost/MeuSite/candidatoeditar.php?candidato=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Mas gostaria que o link ficasse assim:

```
^editar?candidato=([0-9]+)&admin=([0-9]+)/?$
```

Como fazer isto?

Comment: Já tentou adicionar uma barra invertida para escapar o caractere `?` após o "editar"?

Comment: O htaccess não aceita isso